# Implicitly drop the generic argument from List<T>

Tags: c#

TL;DR: (the title gives it away) Can I "Implicitly drop the generic argument from `List<T>`" in one single conversion?

A friend asked me today if it would be possible to implicitly convert a `List<T>` to a non-generic wrapper.

```
var list = new List<_some_type_>();
ObjectResult result = list;
```

The method would look something like this:

```
public static implicit operator ObjectResult(List<T> list) { ... }
```

Clearly, the `T` here is not defined, and the implicit operator's method name is the type name, ergo you can't include a generic parameter to the method name unless the type were actually generic, i.e.:

```
class ObjectResult<T> { ... }
```

Instead of

```
class ObjectResult { ... }
```

The constraints we have with user-defined conversions are (am I missing any?):

1. Cannot convert to or from a Base type
2. Cannot convert to or from an interface.
3. Must make conversion enclosed in one of the two types.

What makes `List<T>` so hard:

1. `List<T>`'s only derivation comes from `Object`; thus we'd have to convert directly from `List<T>`
2. `List<T>` has only interfaces, again, must be directly from `List<T>`
3. `List<T>`, obviously, is compiled up in the framework, so, it must be from our wrapper

I thought of a 2-step solution where there is a middle man we can convert from (whereas the only middle man with `List<T>` is `Object`, and due to rule #1, that's not an option).

```
public class ObjectResult
{
  public static implicit operator ObjectResult(WrapperBase arg) { ... }
}

public class WrapperBase { }

public class ObjectResultWrapper<T> : WrapperBase
{
  public static implicit operator ObjectResultWrapper<T>(List<T> arg) { ... }
}
```

Then, the invoking code would look like this:

```
var list = new List<int>();
ObjectResultWrapper<int> wrap = list;
ObjectResult result = wrap;
```

This doesn't solve the problem really, it's only a work around to drop `T` implicitly (but in two steps, not one). At this point, it'd be easier to have a helper method, and not use user-defined conversions.

There may be arguments against the goal of implicitly dropping the generic argument - I don't have anything else of why he feels this was important. Consider this simply an academic question.

Comment: It seems like a very odd requirement not to be able to convert from any interface.  `List<T>` implements the non-generic IList, which requires no knowledge of `<T>`.

Comment: I hope you're pointing out the requirement on the language - I didn't make those up ... just clarifying your comment is directed at the language, not me :)

Comment: Could you explain what exactly are you trying to do? What is the point of `ObjectResult`?

Comment: I don't understand -- if you want a non-generic list derived from a generic `List<T>` why do you not just interact with it as an `IList`?  That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: @svick and KirkWoll again, I'm approaching this academically, not because of some outcome goal. It was a flat question looking for a flat answer (is it possible to...). Yes there is IList, but the question wasn't "are there non-generic handles for `List<T>`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer: **No, You can't do that with an implicit cast.**

Alternatives:

I think the best thing would be a static `ObjectWrapper.FromList<T>(List<T>)` method.

The wrapper cast is an option as well, though not nearly as elegant.

Comment: In my 2nd rule, I mentioned interface conversions are not allowed, at least that's what I get from the compiler: 'Testing.ObjectResult.implicit operator Testing.ObjectResult(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>)': user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed
I'm using .net 4.0, visual studio 2010 compiler

Comment: @payo: Well, it looks like you can't do that then. Updated answer.

Comment: I agree that the static method is probably the best solution here. But I wouldn't suggest the double cast, it's simply too complicated and confusing.

Comment: I agree that more elegant solution is to use a utility (like a static cast). But again, this question was more a search for what is possible in the language. I apologize for my stubbornness - but imo too many times on SO people look to fix your approach rather than answer the question. Sometimes we are just looking for what is possible, even if our test case for doing it is poor.

Comment: @payo: I noticed that too, and I really hate it when people don't up and answer the question. In this case, the qestion doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

How about declaring a static "Convert" function instead of trying to declare a conversion operator?  Then you could use the compiler's type inference do something like this (calling the conversion method `From`):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
ObjectResult result = ObjectResult.From(list);
```

The `From` method might look like this:

```
public class ObjectResult
{
    //...
    public static ObjectResult From<T>(T arg) { return new ObjectResult<T>(arg); }
    //...
}
public class ObjectResult<T> : ObjectResult
{
    //...
    public ObjectResult(T obj) { /* ... some implementation ... */ }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I agree this is more elegant of a solution. It does appear that the specific goal in mind with the question is not possible.